# How to stop execution of a node.js script?

Tags: node.js, exit

Say I've got this script:

```
var thisIsTrue = false;

exports.test = function(request,response){

    if(thisIsTrue){
        response.send('All is good!');
    }else{
        response.send('ERROR! ERROR!');
        // Stop script execution here.
    }

    console.log('I do not want this to happen if there is an error.');

}
```

And as you can see, I'd like to stop the script from executing any downstream functions if there's an error.

I've managed to achieve this by adding `return;` after the error response is sent:

```
var thisIsTrue = false;

exports.test = function(request,response){

    if(thisIsTrue){
        response.send('All is good!');
    }else{
        response.send('ERROR! ERROR!');
        return;
    }

    console.log('I do not want this to happen if there is an error.');

}
```

But is that the 'correct' way to do things?

**Alternatives**

I've also seen examples that use `process.exit();` and `process.exit(1);`, but that gives me a `502 Bad Gateway` error (I assume because it kills node?).

And `callback();`, which just gave me an 'undefined' error.

What is the 'correct' way to stop a node.js script at any given point and prevent any downstream functions from executing?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Using a `return` is the correct way to stop a function executing.  You are correct in that `process.exit()` would kill the whole node process, rather than just stopping that individual function.  Even if you are using a callback function, you'd want to return it to stop the function execution.

ASIDE: The standard callback is a function where the first argument is an error, or null if there was no error, so if you were using a callback the above would look like:

```
var thisIsTrue = false;

exports.test = function(request, response, cb){

    if (thisIsTrue) {
        response.send('All is good!');
        cb(null, response)
    } else {
        response.send('ERROR! ERROR!');
        return cb("THIS ISN'T TRUE!");
    }

    console.log('I do not want this to happen. If there is an error.');

}
```

Comment: Excellent answer @Tim Brown. Thanks for the bonus explanation of the `standard callback`.

Answer (score 24):

You can use `process.exit()` to *immediately forced terminate* a nodejs program.

You can also pass relevant exit code to indicate the reason.

- `process.exit() //default exit code is 0, which means *success*`
- `process.exit(1) //Uncaught Fatal Exception: There was an uncaught exception, and it was not handled by a domain or an 'uncaughtException' event handler`
- `process.exit(5) //Fatal Error: There was a fatal unrecoverable error in V8. Typically a message will be printed to stderr with the prefix FATAL ERROR`

---

More on [exit codes](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_exit_codes)

Comment: It's what I need

Answer (score 6):

You should use `return`, which will help you respond to what happened. Here's a bit cleaner version, basically first validate whatever you want to validate, rather than encapsulating everything in if{}else{} statements

```
exports.test = function(request, response, cb){

    if (!thisIsTrue) {
        response.send('ERROR! ERROR!');
        return cb("THIS ISN'T TRUE!");
    }

    response.send('All is good!');
    cb(null, response)

    console.log('I do not want this to happen. If there is an error.');

}
```

Another way would be to use `throw`

```
exports.test = function(request, response, cb){

    if (!thisIsTrue) {
        response.send('ERROR! ERROR!');
        cb("THIS ISN'T TRUE!");
        throw 'This isn\'t true, perhaps it should';
    }

    response.send('All is good!');
    cb(null, response)

    console.log('I do not want this to happen. If there is an error.');

}
```

Finally, examples that would stop entire app from further execution:

a) Throw an error, which will also help you debug the app (wouldn't completely stop the app, if the `test()` function was wrapper in `try{}catch(e){}`):

`throw new Error('Something went wrong')`

b) Stop script execution (works with Node.js):

`process.exit()`